# Given a ring R how to obtain a ring $R^1$ with an identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (associative, but need not have an identity). The **usual** extension (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_extension)
of R by $\mathbb{Z}$ gives a ring $R^1$ with an identity element.

How to construct this **usual extension**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nonunital+ring#unitization

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain an extension of $R$ with identity $e$, consider $R^1=R[e]=\{r+me/r\in R, m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$